# Object List view always setting first item no matter what index selected

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I have five columns in my object list view and I want to change the text of item 5 which is the subassembly field in the list view so I am using format cell event. But no matter what I do its only changing the item text at position 0 of the column for some reason I do not no why.

I am using the object listview http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/features.html#custom-row-and-cell-formatting

```
private void olvData_FormatCell(object sender, FormatCellEventArgs e)
{

            List<AllStockQty_Result> result = new List<AllStockQty_Result>();
            if (componentsCCList.Count <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            // If an item is sub assembled we want to check the database  
            // for the qty already saved against this item.
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
            {

                SubAssembledTrackers _subAssembledQty = new SubAssembledTrackers();
               _subAssembledQty.Query.Filters.Add(new Sage.ObjectStore.Filter(SubAssembledTracker.FIELD_PRODUCTIONPLANITEM, _selectedItem.ProductionPlanItemID));

                if (_subAssembledQty.IsEmpty == false && _subAssembledQty.Count >= 1)
                {
                    var first = _subAssembledQty.First;

                    e.Item.Text = first.QtySubAssembled.ToString();

                }
           }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but...

It is changing the text in column 0 because that this is what `e.Item.Text = ...` does. The `Text` of `Item` is literally the text of subitem 0.

Instead, you probably meant `e.SubItem.Text = ...`. This would change just the cell of column 5 (in this case).

**BUT**

You really don't want to do any database access in the `FormatCell` event. It can be called a lot!

It would be better to give column 5 a custom `AspectGetter` which could do the database access once when the data is loaded.

Much better still, change the SQL that underlies your `DataListView` to calculate the right value on the database server!